# Asp.net CkFinder separate folder for different client issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckfinder

I am working on the latest ckfinder 3.4.2 and try to integrate it with my current system built by Asp.net WebForm..The backend for CkFinder would be amazon S3. I can get this working with the static configure file.

However my website got different client. I can get the client_Id after user login in. I would like to set different folder for different client so they can't see each other's folders.

Is there anyway I can set the  folder structure like  {root}/{clientId}/image 
dynamically. So every client got a base folder name with their client Id.

One more thing is I am not using ckeditor and the authentication is not based on OWIN as well.  I just try to integrate the ckfinder to the existing system.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please review [ask]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please have a look at following to links from the docs:
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/configuration_by_code.html
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/howto.html#howto_private_folders